# client (browser, jdbc driver) hangs when trying to connect with docker instance

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, tcp

**Summary**

Client (browser,jdbc drive) hangs connecting to docker.

**Context**

I've been playing with docker and found an oddity: stuff running on my host OS (browser, jdbc driver) "hangs" trying to connect to docker.

I've concluded the issue lies with 'docker' and 'my setup' versus the images themselves, due to the fact that the problem appears:

- with both Tomcat official images as well as with Microsoft's new Sql Server image
- after I've successfully run docker once

**Usecase**

1. Boot my laptop (ubuntu 14.04)
2. Start up docker (see Appendix )
3. Connect with browser http://localhost:8888/. 
   Result: *Success*
4. Shut down docker instance: 'ctrl-c'
5. Start up docker again   (Repeat step 2)
6. Try to connect with browser
   Result: *Browser hangs/spins for 20 minutes, than says "aborted"*

**Notes**

- Docker starts without error in both steps
- After shutdown (step 4), "netstat -aon |grep 8888" shows nothing. So no 'rogue process' is listening on port 888
- Because browser "hangs", rather than says "connection refused", I concluded Docker listens on the port, but doesn't do anything else.

**Version Info**

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5

**Appendix A: Docker file and commands**

*Dockerfile*

```
   Dockerfile: FROM tomcat:8.5.8-jre8-alpine
```

*Commands*

*Create Image:*

```
   $ docker build -t mytomcat_858 .
```

*Start:*

```
   $ docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 mytomcat_858
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, if not the root cause, at least workaround: restarting the docker daemon cleared up all the networking issues:

```
# /etc/init.d/docker restart
```

Answer (score 0):

What command are you executing to start Docker the second time? docker start mytomcat_858? If it starts correctly the second time, can you do docker attach mytomcat_858 and view possible Tomcat errors?

Comment: I've updated the post to include the command: docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 mytomcat_858

Comment: Have you tried running docker in daemon mode instead of interactively?

Answer (score 0):

Try running docker with the following: 
docker run -d -p 8888:8080 mytomcat_858
Then,
You can do docker stop mytomcat_858, and docker start mytomcat_858 to stop and start the process. Do not repeat docker run command for the second time.